# How do populate a column when listing custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type. I want to customize what the user sees when browsing posts of this type.

I've added a column with this function:

```
function stb_replace_title($columns)
{
    unset($columns['title']) ;
    $columns['testimonials']  = _('testimonials');
      return array(
          'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
          'testimonials'  => __('Testimonial'),
          'dates' => __('Date')
    );
}
add_filter('manage_stb_posts_columns', 'stb_replace_title') ;
```

This function appears to add a 'testimonials' column to the posts list.

To test the population of 'testimonials' columnm I've created this function:

```
function stb_output_cols( $column, $post_id )
{

    switch($column) {
    case 'testimonials' :
        echo "got here"  ;
        break ;
    }   

}
add_action(  'manage_stb_custom_column', 'stb_output_cols') ;
```

Ive created this following the codex example, but it doesn't alter the column contents.

So, how do I actually populate the column content for the 'testimonials' column?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hook knows to accept two arguments as shown in the codex example.[1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column#Examples)

`add_action(  'manage_stb_custom_column', 'stb_output_cols', 10, 2);`

See the **$accepted_args**[2](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Parameters) parameter in the function reference of WP codex. Note that the "10" preceding this parameter is the default priority, but you have to include that so the action knows that "2" is the number of accepted args.

> $accepted_args (int) (optional) The number of arguments the hooked
>   function accepts. In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra
>   arguments that are set when the matching do_action() or
>   apply_filters() call is run. For example, the action
>   comment_id_not_found will pass any functions that hook onto it the ID
>   of the requested comment. Default: 1

I believe your `stb_replace_title` needs to merge the new array data with $columns before returning so that these values can be passed to your `stb_output_cols` function later. Otherwise, it will completely replace the original $columns array, savvy?[3](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns#Examples)

```
function stb_replace_title($columns)
{
    unset($columns['title']) ;
    $columns['testimonials']  = _('testimonials');
    // Merge, don't replace, the $columns array.
    return array_merge($columns,
      array('cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
      'testimonials'  => __('Testimonial'),
      'dates' => __('Date')
      )
    );
}
```

To post your content to the page, get the terms, meta data or whatever you want with the appropriate WordPress function and echo the data within the callback function you hooked with `manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`. In your case, the callback function is `stb_output_cols`.

This (modified) example[4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column#Custom_post_type) from codex will get the taxonomy term 'book_author' as well as the post meta 'publisher' and echo their respective values for the given $post_id. The $post_id should already be passed to your function thanks to the above steps.

```
switch ( $column ) {
// Gets and echoes the value for term 'book_author' to the $columns['book_author']
case 'book_author' :
    $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'book_author' , '' , ',' , '' );
        if ( is_string( $terms ) )
        echo $terms;
    else
        _e( 'Unable to get author(s)', 'your_text_domain' );
    break;

// Gets and echoes the the value for post meta key 'publisher' to $columns['publisher'].
case 'publisher' :
    echo get_post_meta( $post_id , 'publisher' , true ); 
    break;
}
```

Of course, this assumes you have added the data to the database already. For example, the publisher for a given post ID could be defined as "HarperCollins" with the function `update_post_meta(42, 'publisher', 'HarperCollins');`.

Now, when the case 'publisher' is true for post ID 42, the publisher column should display "HarperCollins".

There are many possibilities here. Familiarize yourself with the Function Reference[5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) and the index of template tags[6](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) for retrieving the specific data you require.

Comment: See the recent codeblock in this answer and note the explanation between adding and replacing columns in this example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns#Examples

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I've altered the arg list passed into the action. For the moment I don't need to alter the way the array is being altered in the filter: what I have works. I still haven't managed to achieve my goal though: which is to populate the targeted column.

Comment: Hopefully the revised answer will give you some insight into how this works. You can add data to all kinds of stuff via various add/update/insert/create functions found in the reference. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference